# terminate threaded function in python

Tags: python, multithreading, loops

```
 active = True
 while active:
  for i in range(COUNT):    
   response = requests.Session()
   response.mount(engine, gateway)          
   headers = {'Host': 'api.google.com',
                 'Content-type': 'application/json'}
                
   url = 'https://api.google.com'
   data = '{"code":"'+ str("".join(random.choice('0123456789')for i in range(4)))}'
   response = response.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)             
   if response.status_code != 200 or response.json()['result']['displaymessage'] == 'Verification not successed.':
    proc = Thread(target=verify, args=[engine,gateway])
    usleep(10000)
    proc.start()
    #print(response.text)     
   else:  
    gateway.shutdown()
    break
    proc.terminate()
    active = False
```

**i want to stop the threaded loop within else statment . the current code keeps trying without breaking **

Comment: Mind fixing the indendation in the code? It's hard to read this.

Comment: Just for my understanding: You are starting up to 5000 recursive threads per call of the function?

Comment: @KlausD.i just want to thread the function until it gets the right response

Comment: And you are redoing all 5000 calls for every single failure. That's not going to be the right approach.

Comment: You can set a `flag=True` in the `else` block and then inside `for loop`, at the start check if the flag is True;then `break`

Comment: @PravashPanigrahi still not working ,  i just edited the question with your suggestion may you check

Comment: No not like that.let me add the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a `flag` to terminate the process -

```
def verify(engine, gateway):
    global flag
```

Inside for loop:

```
for i in range(5000):
    if flag:
        break
```

Inside else block:

```
else: 
    terminate_flag = True
```